# How to cast bigint to timestamp with time zone in postgres in an update

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

Is there a way to cast a `BIGINT` to `TIMESTAMP` or `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` in Postgres? I need to copy the data from a `BIGINT` column to the `TIMESTAMP` column.

Here is what I have tried:

```
update table
set date__timestamp = date__bigint::timestamp 
where foo = 1;
```

> ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to timestamp without time zone

I changed the timestamp column to a with timezone column and tried this:

```
update table
set date__timestamp = date__bigint::timestamp with time zone at time zone 'PST' 
where foo = 1;
```

> ERROR: cannot cast type bigint to timestamp with time zone

```
update table
set date__timstamp = TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(date__bi / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
where foo = 1;
```

> ERROR: column "date__timestamp" is of type timestamp without time zone
>   but expression is of type text Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast
>   the expression.

The data looks like this.

```
date_bigint: 20181102
date_timestamp: 2018-11-02 17:00:00.000000
```

Do I need to pass default values to the casting?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can cast it to text and use `TO_TIMESTAMP` and the convert to `timestamp at time zone`

```
SELECT 
to_timestamp ( '20181102'::bigint::text,'YYYYMMDD')::timestamp at time zone 'UTC' 
at time zone 'PST' ;

update t
   set date__timestamp = TO_TIMESTAMP(date_bigint::text,'YYYYMMDD')::timestamp 
   at time zone 'UTC' at time zone 'PST'
where foo = 1;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7a9a7c85eb826ee36f2f0e3ae7b08979)

Answer (score 5):

This answer assumes that the `date__bigint` column is storing a UNIX timestamp in seconds since the epoch.  Here is one way to convert to a Postgres timestamp:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET date__timestamp = TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + date__bigint * INTERVAL '1 second'
WHERE foo = 1;
```

That is, we can add some number of seconds to the epoch timestamp to convert your value to a formal Postgres timestamp.

Answer (score 3):

The simpler approach will be to change from **bigint to varchar** then **varchar to timestamp**

```
alter table tablename alter column colname type varchar(30) USING colname::varchar;
```

then

```
alter table tablename alter column colname type timestamp USING colname::timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the column values from Datetime To Date and update the records in the columns using the following. For Example:

```
update table
set StatusDate = DATE("StatusDate")  
where StatusDate is not null;
```

then make the column as varchar.

```
alter table tablename alter column colname type varchar(30) USING colname::varchar;
```

then make the column as Date.

```
alter table tablename alter column colname type Date USING colname::Date;
```